# How to print a different value on view based on the Entity Core MVC Model Value read from the db

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

This is a small excerpt from my ASP .net MVC Entity Core Web app

```
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pass)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pass)
    </dd>
```

The above is from the View's .cshtml file

My question is, if I have to print a value other than what is being returned from the database. For eg., if my database returns 0 or 1 (as string), I would like to print on the view as 'Fail' or 'Pass'.

How can I do this? and from where?

Answer (score 0):

If condition has been made for this purpose. Here is example:

```
@if(model.Pass.Equals("0"))
{
   <p>Fail</p>
}else{
   <p>Pass</p>
}
```

You just need to check if string equals 0 and display the value. I am also advising you to use razor syntax ([Razor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1)) instead of html helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. It worked a charm.

I could now use the code segment inside my .cshtml like this.

```
            @if (item.Pass.Equals("0"))
            {
                <p>Fail</p>
            }
            else
            {
                <p>Pass</p>
            }
```